# How to get the total number of digits at the end of the string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list containing server names like `['oracle0123','oracle0124','oracle0125']`. I want to check how many digits are at the end of the server name, as this varies (as in this case, it is 4). I have a vague idea how this should be done, but my approach didn't work.

```py
v=['oracle0123','oracle0124','oracle0125']

def get_num_position(v):
    for i in v:
        i=i[::-1]
        print('reverse server is-',i)
        for j in i:
            x=0
            if j.isdigit():
                x = x+1
            print(x)
return x

get_num_position(v)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're resetting the value of `x` to 0 for every character. Also, I'm guessing you wanted to print `x` only after looping through each word. This should work *without changing the logic of your code* much:

```py
v=['oracle0123','oracle0124','oracle0125']

def get_num_position(v):
    for i in v:
        i=i[::-1]
        print('reverse server is-',i)
        x=0
        for j in i:
            if j.isdigit():
                x = x+1
        print(x)

get_num_position(v)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) to achieve this:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "oracle1234ad123"
>>> first, _ = re.split("\d+$", s)
>>> len(s) - len(first)
3
```

Note that the code above will fail, if the input string does not end with the number:

```
>>> first, _ = re.split("\d+$", "foobar")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

In Python 3 you could use the `*` assignment, to avoid such errors:

```
>>> first, *rest = re.split("\d+$", "foobar")
>>> first
'foobar'
>>> rest
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work fine for you.

> code

```
v=['oracle0123','oracle0124','oracle0125']

def get_num_position(v):
    count = []
    for i in v:
        tCount = 0
        for j in i:
            if j.isnumeric():
                tCount += 1
        print(tCount)
        count.append(tCount)
    return count
get_num_position(v)
```

> Output:

```
4
4
4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import re

for i in v:
    match=re.search(r'\d+$',i)
    if match:
        print(i, len(match.group()))
    else:
        print(i, '0')
```

Comment: This is almost what I was recommend but it has an undesirable side effect. If the string has numbers in the middle or on the beginning, they will also match and the OP said he wants just those on the end of the string. Try it with something like ```123oracle0123```, for example.

Comment: Fixed it, try it :)

Answer (score 0):

### With a regular expression:

- `r'\d*$'`

  - `$` from the end
  - `\d*` find all the digits
- [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) finds the pattern
- [`.group`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.group) returns the match group
- [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) determines the length of the group
- **Assumes there is at least one number at the end**
- Using a [List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
- Examples have been provided with numbers

  - Only at the end
  - the beginning and end
  - the middle and the end
  - the beginning middle and end
- The code only returns the `len` of numbers at the end

```py
import re

values = ['oracle01234',
          'oracle012468',
          'oracle01258575',
          '0123oracle0123',
          '0123oracle0124555',
          '0123oracle01255',
          'ora0123cle01234',
          'or0123acle0124333333',
          'o0123racle01254',
          '123or0123acle0124333333']


count_of_end_numbers = [len(re.search(r'\d*$', x).group()) for x in values]

print(count_of_end_numbers)

>>> [5, 6, 8, 4, 7, 5, 5, 10, 5, 10]
```